# Which pattern to use to replace boolean hell

Tags: design-patterns

i have nested if / else that depened on few booleans 
its game engine update function and its called each milisecound or so 
now i have few conditions pf layers movments 
and its go's something like this :

```
function update()
{
  if(b_layer_1 == true)
  {
     b_layer_1->posY(-2)
     if(b_layer_1->posY() = 150)
     {
       b_layer_1 = false ;
       b_layer_2 = true ;
       b_layer_3 = false ;
     }
   }
    if(b_layer_2 == true)
   {
     b_layer_2->posY(-2)
     if(b_layer_2->posY() = 400)
     {
       b_layer_1 = false ;
       b_layer_2 = false ;
       b_layer_3 = true ;
     }
   }
    if(b_layer_3 == true)
   {
     b_layer_3->posY(-2)
     if(b_layer_3->posY() = 700)
     {
       b_layer_1 = false ;
       b_layer_2 = false ;
       b_layer_3 = false ;
      // ... Here i can have more layers boolean's 
      //...
     }
   }
   //.. it can continue up to 20 layers to control with booleans ...




  }
}
```

im looking for somekind of ( im not sure ) state pattern to ged rid of this Boolean hell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The State pattern is based more on exclusive states of the application. In your case, it's not A or B or C, but rather A and maybe B and maybe C. It looks like you would use some kind of collection of a key and pair (I don't know c and c++, is there something like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` like in C#?) where the key is your layer object and value is a custom type holding information about settings and actions that should occur when its "layer is true". In pseudocode

```
for all layers in layers_collection
  if layer is true then
    layer.pos(-2)
    if layer.post == layer.settings.expectedPosition
        layer.setMyBools
```

This is what I would do. I could actually write you a C# code, but I guess that wouldn't say you much more than this one. Maybe consider taggin your question with a specific language tag?

Comment: but still i will have to deal with booleans Decisions right ? 
if i understand you right ?

Comment: Oh, you ment that. You will have to, but it's up to you how you will do it. I'll add example.

Comment: i know i will have to , but i realy what to find way to do it at the minimum . mybe some kind of mask on/off bit arithmetic?

Comment: Ok, no example. Just use that same principle - stuff all booleans in a collection and then use a loop to assign them. If they should have different values, use a dictionary. Or as you suggest, a mask.

Comment: Hey thanks  again , do you have some link to some example ? 
its abit hard to understand why i need the boolean in collection 
and how do i change the state ?
do you have name to your pattern of idea ?

Comment: Unfurtunately, it's not a pattern. It's just a sheer logic solution for me. Look at it this way: you have many similar things and you want them be set elegantly. So you put them in a bag and run a loop on this bag instead of settings them separately.

Comment: @user63898 If you find my answer useful, could you mark it as accepted so that others know that it solved your problem at least partially?